# Regex to search when a text is found and other text is missing

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
application ONE {
    protocol tcp;
    destination-port 50;
}
application TWO {
    protocol udp;
    destination-port 51;
    inactivity-timeout 800;
}
application THREE {
    protocol udp;
    destination-port 500;
}
```

I need to search for each `application`, when `protocol` is `udp`, if `inactivity-timeout` is different from 1800 (app TWO) or `protocol` is `udp` and no inactivity is defined (app THREE).
I've solved the first case with a regular expression:

```
(?s)(?=protocol udp).*(inactivity-timeout (?!1800))
```

But I've not found way to get the second.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You flagged this with Java, so I'm giving you a Java solution although I'm not sure from your post if that's that what you desire.

Personally I would split the problem into two parts. First, extracting the applications, and second, checking if an application meet the requirements. Here is my try.

```
public class ApplicationReadOut {

    public static String EXAMLPLE = "application ONE {\r\n"
        +"    protocol tcp;\r\n"
        +"    destination-port 50;\r\n"
        +"}\r\n"
        +"application TWO {\r\n"
        +"    protocol udp;\r\n"
        +"    destination-port 51;\r\n"
        +"    inactivity-timeout 800;\r\n"
        +"}\r\n"
        +"application THREE {\r\n"
        +"    protocol udp;\r\n"
        +"    destination-port 500;\r\n"
        +"}\r\n";

    public boolean checkApplication(String app) {
        String[] lines = app.split("\r\n");
        boolean udp = false;
        boolean timeoutDiffers = true;
        boolean timeoutMentioned = false;
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.trim().equals("protocol udp;"))
                udp = true;
            if (line.trim().equals("inactivity-timeout 1800;"))
                timeoutDiffers = false;
            if (line.trim().startsWith("inactivity-timeout "))
                timeoutMentioned = true;
        }
        return udp & (timeoutDiffers | !timeoutMentioned);
    }

    public String[] extractApplications(String text) {
        String[] applications = text.split("}(\r*\n*)*"); 
        // the \r\n thing is to ignore blank lines in between applications
        ArrayList<String> goodApps = new ArrayList<String>(applications.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < applications.length; i++) {
            applications[i] += "}"; // this was removed by split
            if (checkApplication(applications[i]))
                goodApps.add(applications[i]);
        }
        return goodApps.toArray(new String[0]);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationReadOut aro = new ApplicationReadOut();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aro.extractApplications(EXAMLPLE)));
    }

}
```

I hope this is useful and you can modify this to fit your needs :-)

Comment: Hi GreenThor, thanks for your response. It was a mistake from my side to tag it with Java, I mean to java regular expressions, I can´t do that :-(

Comment: Can't do anything about that, sorry. But it's nice of you to reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
application\s*([a-z]*)\s*{(?=(?=\s*protocol udp*)(?!inactivity-timeout.*))|(?=(?=\s*protocol udp*)(?!inactivity-timeout\s1800))(?=})
```

You need to use `/img` for multiline, case-insensitive and global search.

Explanation and your example [here](https://regex101.com/r/nE6lK0/3).

Comment: Hi Nils, thanks a lot for your response. I´ve been testing for a while and i´m not sure it´s working as expected. I think that the work is being done by the first OR. If I change innactivity value to 1800 in APP TWO the regex still matches it. If i delete the second OR the regex still matches both APP TWO and THREE. Thanks a lot for your help